# How to get the current domain name in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a domain that has multiple sites underneath it.

In my `Startup.cs` I have the following code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "MyAppName";
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpanTimeSpan.FromMinutes(300);
     })
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext, Guid>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

On the production machine all my sites are in a subfolder under the same site in `IIS` so I don't want to use the default domain as the cookie name otherwise different sites cookies will have the same name

What I want is to get the current domain e..g mydomain.com and then append it to an explicit cookiename per site that I specify in `Startup.cs` e.g.

```
 var domain = "get the server domain here somehow e.g. domain.com";
 ...
 options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "MyAppName." + domain;
```

How do I do this?

The reason I ask:

I can see in Chrome developer tools the cookies fall under separate domain names of the site I am accessing. However I sometimes somehow still get the situation of when I log into the same site on two different servers, that I can't log into one and it doesn't log any error. The only solution is to use another browser so I can only assume by the symptoms can only be to do with the cookie.

So my question is really just a personal preference question as in my environment I would prefer to append the domain name to the cookie name although the cookie can only belong to a specific domain.

Comment: If they have separate domain names the cookies are already separated. I don't really get the actual problem

Comment: Yes the cookies are separate underneath each domain if I look in Chrome dev tools. Let just say  I want to do this not for a specific reason but just so the cookie name includes the domain name for my personal preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, i would  store domain name in configuration. So it would enable me to change it for current environment.

```
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = Configuration["DomainName"];
```

If you don't like this way you can override cookie option on signin event like this(i am not sure below ways are good):

```
Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
{
   OnSigningIn = async (context) =>
   {
       context.Options.CookieName = "MyAppName." + context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.ToString();
   }
}
```

Or catch first request in configure and override options

```
        bool firstRequest = true;
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if(firstRequest)
            {
                options.CookieName = "MyAppName." + context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.ToString();
                firstRequest = false;
            }
            await next();
        });
```

Also see similar question [How to get base url without accessing a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864550/how-to-get-base-url-without-accessing-a-request)

Comment: I recently moved to Docker. While my webserver listens to localhost:5000, it is actually hosted on <domain.com>:80, therefore it has little use to check the hosting parameters from Startup.cs. So for me the configuration setting is the best, easiest and most flexible way.

Comment: @Rob van der Veer, it can be the best, as you said, for your case but not for everyone because there are applications that serve more than one domain.

Answer (score 0):

I found this other way. also [I have a blog to documented that](https://aprende-a-programar.com/b/Know-domain-name-from-StartUp-in-MVC/).

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private WebDomainHelper DomainHelper;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(DomainHelper.GetDomain()) });
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            DomainHelper = new WebDomainHelper(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(
                endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                }
            );
        }
    }



    public class WebDomainHelper
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor;
        public WebDomainHelper(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            ContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        /// 

        /// Get domain name
        /// 

        public string GetDomain()
        {
            string serverURL;
            try
            {
                serverURL = $"{ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value}/";
            }
            catch
            {
                serverURL = string.Empty;
            }
            return serverURL;
        }
    }
```